# Mapbox: Custom Annotation Callout

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

In mapbox for ios using swift what is the correct way to create a custom layer in the annotation bubble using the new Mapbox for iOS I know in the previous version you could get something similar following this [link](https://www.mapbox.com/guides/station-finder-part-3/) but the new official version seems pretty different. Also the intention is to change the callout, possibly just displaying a `UIView` in its place

Answer (score 0):

The callout uses the same dependency as the old SDK, which is [SMCalloutView](https://github.com/nfarina/calloutview). It should be just as customizable as in that guide you linked to.

Comment: yeah I've found currently it is not the only thing that is allowed is the name and subtitle. The actual callout view is hidden in the official version of the api